# elif statement returning the "lost" result each time incorrectly. (homework)

Tags: python

I have updated my code with the changes made.  I am still getting incorrect results...

```
# Import statements
import random

# Define main function that will ask for input, generate computer choice,
# determine winner and show output when finished.

def main():
    # Initialize Accumulators
    tie = 0
    win = 0
    lose = 0
    score = 0
    # initialize variables

    user = 0
    computer = 0

    # Initialize loop control variable
    again = 'y'
    while again == 'y':
        userInput()
        computerInput()
        if score == win:
            print('You won this round, good job!')
            win += 1
        elif score == tie:
            print('You tied this round, please try again!')
            tie += 1
        else:
            print('You lost this round, please try again!')
            lose += 1

        again = input('Would you like to play another round (y/n)? ')
    #determine winning average
    average = (win / (win + lose + tie))
    print('You won ', win, 'games against the computer!')
    print('You lost ', lose, 'games against the computer.')
    print('You tied with the computer for', tie)
    print('Your winning average is', average)
    print('Thanks for playing!!')

# get user input for calculation
def userInput():
    print('Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissor!')
    print('Please make your selection and and Good Luck!')
    print('1) Rock')
    print('2) Paper')
    print('3) Scissor')
    user = int(input('Please enter your selection here: '))
    print('You selected', user)

# get compter input for calculation
def computerInput():
    computer = random.randint(1, 3)
    print('The computer chose', computer)

def getScore():
    if user == 1 and computer == 3:
        score = win
        return score
    elif user == 2 and computer == 1:
        score = win
        return score
    elif user == 3 and computer == 2:
        score = win
        return score

    elif user == computer:
        score = tie
        return score
    else:
        score = lose
        return score


# Call Main

main()
```

Comment: 1) Don't post your program in its entirety here - figuring out the precise part where things go wring you your responsibility, not ours (and might also help you solve problems yourself)
2) After your edit you erased your actual question AND removed all formating. Please be more careful.

Comment: I was trying to show the few users that were helping me that I had updated the program based on their advice.  I am trying to figure out my problems myself, and have revised and changed, and rewritten this program for a week, and cannot figure out where my decision statement is going awry. I will keep formatting in mind in the future, thank you.

Comment: If you want to show changes you made it is more appropriate to show them *in addition* to the original question instead of erasing it. Anyone that comes here later will have no idea what is going on and will have a hard time learning something from this.

Comment: The purpose of stackoverflow is to gather a collection of questions and answers that will be generally useful to others in the future.  That is why editing your question is undesirable.  It may not have hindered "the few users that were helping" from giving you further advice, but it makes the "question" useless to future users.  (Destroying the formatting, of course, makes it hard for anyone to help you.)

Comment: I wasn't calling global variables into each function for assignment.  I got it working perfect!  Thank you guys!!!  Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I will keep all of this in mind in the future.  I apologize for not realizing the implications.  Thank you for letting me know, it is greatly appreciated, as I find this site helpful, and hope to contribute as well as gain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `userInput()` calls the function "userInput", but you discard the result. The same remark applies to `computerInput()`.
2. `userInput == 1` asks whether the *function* `userInput` itself is equal to 1. It isn't. The same remark applies to `computerInput == 3` and the others.
3. In the function "userInput", `userInput = ...` binds the name "userInput" to the result of the expression. This makes "userInput" a local variable of the function. The function doesn't explcitly return anything, therefore it returns `None`.
4. If you're using Python 3, `input` returns a string, and you should convert its result to an int. If you're using Python 2, `input` evaluates whatever is entered, which isn't safe; you should use `raw_input` instead and convert its result to an int.

Comment: I have updated function and variable names: functions = userInput and computerInput; variables: computer and user.  I still cannot get it to return the correct results :(

Answer (score 4):

In Python:

```
>>> print("3" == 3)
False
```

Strings and integers are values of different data types, and will not compare equal. Try changing your input to:

```
userInput = int(input('Please enter your selection here: '))
```

This will convert the *string* typed by the user to a *number* for later comparison. (Note that I have assumed you are using Python 3.x, because `input()` behaves slightly differently in Python 2.x.)

Note that this will throw an error if you type anything other than a number.

**Update:** As pointed out by @FelipeFG in the comments below, you are also overwriting the *function* `userInput` with the *value* typed by the user. You'll need to change the name of one or the other, for example:

```
def getUserInput():
    ...
```

Also don't forget to change the place where you call the function. Do the same for `computerInput` (change to `getComputerInput`).

Later on, you can change those to actual functions that *return* values.

Comment: You probably also want your functions to return values.

Comment: This is incorrect. input() will treat the string from the console as python source and `eval` it, thereby returning an int.

Comment: moreover, he is also attributing a value to the name that held a function! After the first time he runs userInput(), "userInput" will no longer be the function, but the number input by the user. Next call to userInput (next iteration) will hopefully fail! You should return a value and store it in a variable (with a different name then the function's).

Comment: @phant0m: You're thinking of the old behaviour of `input()` in Python 2.x.

Comment: @alxbl: One thing at a time. It's better to start with a working program and incrementally improve it, than to try to fix everything at once.

Comment: @FelipeFG: Good catch! That will be the next bug to fix. :)

Comment: adding int to my input statement isn't changing the results determined by the elif statement??  I did update and test.  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @Greg: `userInput = ` You don't want to overwrite the function, no?

Comment: @ FelipeFG: I updated my variable names to user & computer, and returned their value.   Now each iteration is showing "tied" where before it was showing "lose"...

Comment: @Alli OGrady: Okay, you're going to have to apply some debugging to determine what is going on. Use `print(repr(userInput))` and `print(repr(computerInput))` after getting the inputs to compare the *actual* values that your `if` statement is working with.

Comment: @ Greg:  I know that I probably sound completely ignorant, but how do I use the print(repr()) command?  I want to thank you in advance for your assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare against the return value of your function, not the function itself.

Also:

```
again = input('Would you like to play another round (y/n)? ')
```

This will throw an exception if you enter `y` or `n`, because there is no defined identifier of that name! What you want to use instead is `raw_input()`

**Edit**: As pointed out by Greg, this only applies to Python 2.x. You seem to be using Python3 though.

Comment: Your answer is appropriate for Python 2.x, but in Python 3.x the `input()` function works like the old `raw_input()`.

Comment: My loop is working fine.  I believe the incorrect calculation is my only issue in the function of the program.  I may be wrong thought...

Comment: It threw an exception for me because I was using Python 2.6 ;)